# downloading folder from ssh to local machine

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, scp

I have a specific problem.

I have a server(say x) , first I have to connect to the x server using ssh x@domain. Then there is an internal server y again I have to connect to that specific domain using ssh. I have to download a folder in server y. I tried using scp after logging into x, using

**scp -r /data/home/path          /Users/username/Desktop**

I got the following error

cp: cannot create regular file `/Users/username/Desktop': No such file or directory

please help me in downloading the folder

Comment: If from A you ssh to B and from B you do an scp to C then you are targeting as destination for the files to be copied the B server. If you want to copy to A you have go undoing your steps.

Comment: @Juan can u please elaborate the steps ?

Comment: Copy from c to b then exit from b and copy from b to a

Comment: @Juan It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That error is because the destination /Users/username/Desktop doesn't exist on server X.

However, there's more going on here. That command is just trying to copy the first folder locally because there is no host information.

You should run from X:

```
scp -r usery@servery:/data/home/path destination
```

And then repeat the process from your machine using serverx information.